# Binding selectable options to drop down list

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Hi I have following data that I am trying to fill it in a form in a drop down list so that integer values are shown as selectable numbers.

```
 "data": [ { "pName": "201310"},
    { "pName": "201320" },
    {  "pName": "201330" }, ]
}

<form id="form">
<table id="roll">
<tr>
<td><select class="form-dropdown" id="pId" name="pName"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Jquery to load the options is

```
 function fnLoadP() {
              alert("in");
              var id=3345
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'get'
                  , dataType: 'jason'
                  , url: " ./periodDDown?Id=" + id + "&"
                   , sucess: function (rdata) {
                    $.each(rdata.data, function (pName, value) {
                                        $("#pId").append($("<select></select>").val(value).html(pName));
                                    });
                                },
                  error: function (result) {
                      alert("error");
                  }
              });  
          };
```

I dont get any errors data is being fetched properly as shown in array on top. Problem is with sucess function the way I am trying to bind the data with dropdown has some problem. Please let me know how to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to append options in the drop down like this

```
$.each(rdata.data, function (pName, value) {
    $("#pId").append("<option value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");
});
```